# how to skip query exection if input array is empty or not exit in mongoose aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to find record by using aggregate query, and if any of given input is empty array then need to skip that query. In the below code, i have give one empty array to "brandFilter", then that query need to skip $in execution. If it has some array [one, two], then it will give related matched output

### Example

```
{ $filter: {
                    input: '$products',
                    as: 'item',
                    cond: {  $and: [
                        {
                            $gte: ['$$item.prodprice', Number(price)],
                        },
                        { $in: [ "$$item.brand", brandArr ] }  
                    ]}
                }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following filter would get us the expected output:

```
{
    $filter:{
        "input":"$products",
        "as":"item",
        "cond":{
            $and:[
                {
                    $gte: ['$$item.prodprice', Number(price)]
                },
                {
                    $or:[
                        {
                            $eq:[brandArr[0],undefined]
                        },
                        {
                            $in: [ "$$item.brand", brandArr ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```